# If $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then, for all $\delta>0$, the set $E_{\delta} = \{x\in A; w(f;x)\ge \delta\}$ has volume $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> If $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then, for all $\delta>0$, the set
>   $E_{\delta} = \{x\in A; w(f;x)\ge \delta\}$ has volume $0$

Since this question involves the oscilation, I thought about using the theorem that says that if a function $f$ is integrable, then

$$\sum_{B\in P}w_B\ vol \ B <\epsilon$$

To prove that this set has measure $0$, we must cover it by an enumerable quantity of blocks such that the sum of their volumes is $<\epsilon$. I think it has something to do with the oscilation being as big as I want to, so the integral will have a problem in $E_{\delta}$. Could somebody help me?

Comment: You might want to assume that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $vol(E_\delta) > 0$ and try to show that this implies that $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: But what the volume being > 0 implies? Can't find a connection. Only thing I know is that such set having volume not zero implies that its interior is not empty

Comment: If the interior of $E_\delta > 0$ then $f$ must have an uncountable number of discontinuities and so it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Why uncountable number of discontinueties?

Comment: Because $E_\delta$ contains an interval.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the relation between the oscillation and discontinuity, would you mind explaining? Thanks

Comment: Surprised that you get answers so late? The reason might be that you haven't defined the function $w(f;x)$. So most readers will have gone away after reading your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a Riemann integrable function $f$ over a bounded rectangle $A$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists, by the Riemann integrability criterion,  a partition $P$ such that upper and lower sums satisfy

$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \delta \epsilon.$$

The LHS can be decomposed into contributions from sub-rectangles that meet $E_\delta$ and  those that do not, namely

$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) = \sum_{R \cap E_\delta \neq \phi}(M_R - m_R) \text{vol}(R) + \sum_{R \cap E_\delta = \phi}(M_R - m_R) \text{vol}(R)$$

where $M_R = \sup_{x \in R} f(x)$ and $m_R = \inf_{x \in R} f(x).$

Since$M_R - m_R \geqslant 0$ we have

$$\sum_{R \cap E_\delta \neq \phi}(M_R - m_R) \text{vol}(R) \leqslant U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \delta \epsilon.$$

You should be able to show (try) that for each rectangle represented in the sum on the left there is a point $c \in R$ where $M_r - m_r \geqslant \omega(f;c) \geqslant \delta$.

Hence,

$$\delta \sum_{R \cap E_\delta \neq \phi} \text{vol}(R) < \delta \epsilon.$$

What can you conclude?